# JavaScript string manipulation: remove prefix, suffix and lowercase first (in single line without assignments), possible?

Tags: javascript

Hope that this will not be closed, I can't find any suitable questions.

1. **Prefix** is a variable
2. **Suffix** is always the word `Value`
3. Resulting value should have the **first letter lowercase**

Code so far, missing the lowercase for the first letter:

```
// Input: { toastDurationValue: 3000, toastPositionValue: 'bottom' }
// Wanted: { duration: 3000, position: 'bottom' }

const options = Object.keys(element.dataset)
  .filter(k => k.startsWith(prefix))
  .reduce((prev, curr) => ({
    ...prev,
    [curr.slice(prefix.length).replace(/(Value)$/, '')]: element.dataset[curr]
  }), {});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
.toLowerCase()
```

after

```
.replace(/(Value)$/, '')
```

Here:

```
// Input: { toastDurationValue: 3000, toastPositionValue: 'bottom' }
const options = Object.keys(element.dataset)
  .filter(k => k.startsWith(prefix))
  .reduce((prev, curr) => ({
    ...prev,
    [curr.slice(prefix.length).replace(/(Value)$/, '').toLowerCase()]: element.dataset[curr]
  }), {});
console.log(options);
```

Output:

```
{ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom' }
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in one statement, in an elaborate (difficult to read) way using [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase). The original string stays as it is:

```js
let str = 'hellorandomWORDValue';
const prefix = 'hello';

const str2 = str.replace(prefix, "").slice(0,-5)[0].toUpperCase() + str.replace(prefix, "").slice(0,-5).slice(1)

console.log(str);
console.log(str2);
```

`slice(0,5)` -> removes the last 5 letter, so basically removes `Value` suffix.

`replace(prefix,"")` -> replaces first instances of the variable string `prefix`. So basically removes the prefix.

`[0].toUpperCase()` -> takes out the first character and makes it uppercase.

`.slice(1)` -> takes out rest of the string (from 1st index). Basically, rest of the string after first character.

```
const options = Object.keys(element.dataset)
  .filter(k => k.startsWith(prefix))
  .reduce((prev, curr) => ({
    ...prev,
    [curr.replace(prefix, "").slice(0,-5)[0].toUpperCase() + curr.replace(prefix, "").slice(0,-5).slice(1)]: element.dataset[curr]
  }), {});
```

Answer (score 2):

May below snippet can contribute to your solution.

```js
const obj = { toastDurationValue: 3000, toastPositionValue: 'bottom' }
const prefix = 'toast';

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = obj[key.substring(0, key.lastIndexOf('Value')).replace(prefix, '').toLowerCase()] = obj[key];
    delete obj[key];
})

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason mapping entries rather than reducing the object feels a tiny bit better to me:

```js
const simplify_key = (key, prefix_length) =>
  key[prefix_length].toLowerCase() + key.substring(prefix_length + 1, key.length - 5);

const extract_options = (dataset, prefix = 'toast') =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(dataset)
      .filter(([key]) => key.startsWith(prefix))
      .map(([key, val]) => [simplify_key(key, prefix.length), val])
  );

console.log(extract_options({
  toastDurationValue: 3000,
  toastPositionValue: 'bottom',
  toastMoreTermsValue: 'thing',
  otherDataItem: 'wibble'
}));
```